# How to fade in changing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm changning some html via JAvascript and I want to fade in the text.

This is the javascript:

```
        var int = self.setInterval(function(){
            if(!isPaused){
                changeBG();
            }
        }, 3500);

        function changeBG(){
            //array of backgrounds
            now = (now+1) % array.length ;
            $('.documentary').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');
            document.getElementById('film-detail').innerHTML = array2[now];
            }
```

And this is my CSS which I think should cause it to fadeIn:

```
.documentary-bg div.film-title {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class='film-title' id="film-detail"></div>
```

I've tried a number of approaches and it won't fade in!

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/a3tb4hq3/). Is there a `<div class="documentary-bg">` in your HTML?

Comment: The background fades in just fine.  It is the text in innerHTML which I cannot get to fadein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use css transitions?

```
.text {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.text.fadeOut {
  opacity:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tvakyp2c/

Comment: I'm trying to run it within a setInterval and that seems to be stopping the transition

Comment: By adding a setTimeout to delay the second change, this works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to fade in but did you know that you can just use:

```js
$(selector).fadeIn(speed,easing,callback)
```

in your case would probably be:

```
$('.documentary-bg').fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Background is working fine.  It is the text in innerHTML which won't fade on change.  I think because I'm running it within setInterval

Comment: @HenryM does the text has it's own class or ID?